# Looking for a way to encrypt/decrypt network data between PHP and iOS

Tags: php, ios, encryption

I would like to use a shared key between my server and the clients' iOS apps (Would change probably in each version of the app) so that it would be possible to encrypt data and decrypt it. 
For the least I need this working on the iOS side, encrypting the data it is about to send. 
I don't want bots or malicious users scanning my db. I need to encrypt location, timestamp and some data along with it.

The original string might be 100-200 chars long. before encryption.
Using SSL would help evade "man in the middle". But I need encrypted URLs sent. Something like:

1. iOS side request:
   NSString* theKey = "Kazam";
   NSString* theString ="`lat=10.222455`&`lon=23.342224455`&`ID=3476rghfb3uf34f`&`timestamp=34325224433`"
   param=urlencode(encryptString(theString,theKey));

   https://www.mydomain.com/page1.php?**param=sdhcy39h923498ufdd**
2. server receives param and decrypts it.
   PHP server:
   $theKey = "Kazam";
   $decrypted=decryptString($GET['param'],$theKey);
3. then returns the data to the client.

again, I don't mind if that data sent from the server would not be encrypted. 
After all, the client is the one who can possibly scan the DB.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I don't quite get why plain SSL isn't sufficient.

Comment: Plain SSL encrypts the URL as well, you don't need anything else.

Comment: Are you sure F.X? I am pretty sure Hotmail is https, and yet the urls are not encrypted. well not as SSL might encrypt them as I would think. Making the whole string encrypted

Comment: SSL encrypts the URL. If the URL is `https://yourdomain.com/stuff&morestuff` then `GET /stuff&morestuff` is encrypted.

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a URL to pass parameters. That is, use POST requests instead of GET requests. It's as easy as that! Sending a POST request via HTTPS is very secure. **Update:** Yes, GET requests are encrypted over HTTPS. But POST just seems safer to me for some (maybe unfounded) reason. I just don't like the idea that variables or passwords could be stored in browser caches or server logs. Plus it's easier for a hacker to set up a malicious link with GET.

Also, don't forget, if something is on the web, anyone can send requests, so you should  probably use server-side authentication unless you are totally sure that you can decipher between legitimate requests and fraudulent requests.

Comment: So, you mean there's no way reasonable way users can manipulate data?

Comment: That would take a user-password which the users might not like

Comment: Anyone on the web could send any request they want to your server right now, as far as I can tell. However, they won't be able to *see* what *you* send if you send it over HTTPS. You can do authentication within your app using your own username and password. Users don't have to log in. That will prevent a hacker from just opening a browser and sending any request to your server that they want to send.

Comment: So let me get this straight. Once on https (I am currently developing, and I am NOT on SSL yet, so I can't verify this) the total messages sent between the machines would be completely blocked out from the user? There would be no way the user can manipulate data?

Comment: HTTPS *is* simply HTTP over SSL (or TLS nowadays). SSL will always be setup before any data is send; no data is send without confidentiality and integrity protection - unless there is a failure in the SSL protocol of course.

Comment: With HTTPS, There is no way other people can *see* what you are passing. Bank account numbers and credit card numbers are sent with HTTPS everyday. However, if you have a script that gets a user's information, someone anonymous hacker could still retrieve that user data if they knew what request to send, which would be easy to find out, especially if they were already a user. Someone could also change or delete an account if the knew what requests to send. If you are worried about that, you should use authentication so that only authenticated users can send requests.

Answer (score 1):

The entire HTTP request is encrypted when using SSL (HTTPS), so you can send the data in the URL as you already do.

Comment: Isn't hotmail SSL encrypted? If you look at their URLs, they seem not encrypted to the eye.

Comment: I thought it is SSL as long as the protocol says https in the beginning of the URL

Comment: SSL is secure socket layer, TLS is transpot layer security. Both provide, as the name implies, encryption and integrity checks *during transport only*. So the URL you see will be *send* encrypted, but won't show up encrypted at the server or in the browser.

Comment: So, this emphasizes my need. I care for the user to not be able to decipher what they are sending.